# How do I print out an angular expression as a string out on the page?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an **angular expression** `{{list}}`
I don't want angular to execute it - I want to escape it.
I want to print them out as HTML code on my page.

```
  <xmp>
 
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="list in lists" class="input">
        {{list}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  
  </xmp>
```

I kept getting

[image]

## [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/u2ab014j/1/)

What is the best way do something like that ?

Comment: you could change your delimiter `$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');` and then `{{}}` won't render

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 'ng-non-bindable' in the element.

Example:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>This is a {{profile}}</div>
```

Will simply show:

```
This is a {{profile}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may escape angular curly braces with multiple ways, using HTML comments, `ng-non-bindable` tag or even a interrupting HTML element

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="lists = ['one','two','three'];">
    echo: {{lists}}</br>
    escape 1: <code ng-non-bindable>{{lists}}</code></br>
    escape 2:{{lists}<!-- -->}</br>
    escape 3:{{lists}<span/>}</br>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u2ab014j/2/)

Keep in mind that you may easily change curly to braces to whatever you want:

```
var app = angular.module('app')
  .config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
}]);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DNSt99Tl7zQPtHDYEwQD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

```
<xmp ng-non-bindable>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="list in lists" class="input">{{list}}</li>
  </ul>
</xmp>
```

Output

> Data

```
lists = ['one','two','three'];
```

> Angular

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="list in lists" class="input">{{list}}</li>
</ul>
```

> Output

```
one
two
three
```

**UPDATE**

To use HTML syntax...

Here is how StackOverflow does it.

For this piece of HTML

```
<xmp>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="list in lists" class="input">{{list}}</li>
  </ul>
</xmp>
```

They use this...

```
<pre class="default prettyprint prettyprinted">
  <code>
    <span class="tag">&lt;xmp</span>
    <span class="pln"> </span>
    <span class="atn">ng-non-bindable</span>
    <span class="tag">&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span>
    <span class="tag">&lt;ul&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span>
    <span class="tag">&lt;li</span>
    <span class="pln"> </span>
    <span class="atn">ng-repeat</span>
    <span class="pun">=</span>
    <span class="atv">"list in lists"</span><span class="pln"> </span>
    <span class="atn">class</span><span class="pun">=</span>
    <span class="atv">"input"</span>
    <span class="tag">&gt;</span>
    <span class="pln">{{list}}</span>
    <span class="tag">&lt;/li&gt;</span>
    <span class="pln"> </span>
    <span class="tag">&lt;/ul&gt;</span>
    <span class="pln"> </span>
    <span class="tag">&lt;/xmp&gt;</span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Do something similar but with your own styling. It looks like you will be having static HTML for a lesson of some sorts, but you could just make the rendered text in a string format that gets rendered dynamically with the correct classes using ngClass.